How to remove trailing space from string and preserve faces
I have a string that can contain trailing spaces.
For instance hello, I have spaces              
I wrote the following function to remove said spaces:
(defun filter-last-spaces (text)
  (let*
      (
       (text (reverse text))
       (found-non-space nil)
       (reversed (mapcar (lambda (current) (if (and (not found-non-space)
                                                    (equal current ? ))
                                               ? 
                                             (progn
                                               (setq found-non-space t)
                                               (char-to-string current)
                                               current
                                               )))
                         text)
                 )
       (reversed (mapconcat (lambda (current) (char-to-string current)) reversed))
       )
    (format "%s" (reverse reversed))
    )
  )

This function receives a string, and maps every char in reverse. As soon as it finds a non whitespace character it stops processing the input and returns everything "as is"
What I don't like about it is that:

If the string had faces, it removes the faces
It seems to be a bit hacky and too complicated.

Is there a simpler way to do this, that preserves faces (things like highlighting and such)? Thanks in advance.

string-trim-right

Could you make this an answer so that I can mark it as correct please? Thank you very much ^_^

Crikey.  A few seconds of C-h f string<TAB><TAB>, or looking through C-h i g (elisp)Creating Strings, would have saved you a lot of time.

This can be done using string-trim-right:
string-trim-right is a byte-code-function in `subr.el'.

(string-trim-right STRING &optional REGEXP)

Trim STRING of trailing string matching REGEXP.

REGEXP defaults to  "[ \t\n\r]+".

  Other relevant functions are documented in the string group.
  Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 24.4.
  This function does not change global state, including the match data.


The chances of you ever needing to manipulate a string as a sequence of individual characters are extremely slim.
Obviously rpluim's answer is the best one but, as an addendum, even when the exact function you need doesn't exist, you can very easily do regexp matching on strings and extract arbitrary substrings.  E.g.:
(let ((str (propertize "hello, I have spaces              "
                       :face 'warning))
      (regexp (rx bos
                  (group (*? anything)) ;; sub-group 1
                  (zero-or-more " ")
                  eos)))
  (string-match regexp str)
  (match-string 1 str)) ;; sub-group 1

or simpler:
(let ((str (propertize "hello, I have spaces              "
                       :face 'warning)))
  (replace-regexp-in-string (rx (zero-or-more " ") eos) "" str))

Both of which return:
=> #("hello, I have spaces" 0 20 (:face warning))

That's basically what string-trim-right and similar do :-)
